# How to ignore/accept/avoid SSLHandshakeException while trying to check for broken links?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

I'm trying to verify if a link is throwing `response code` other than `200`. Link, that I'm trying to verify is `https://` and after process has run, it throws this error --

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: 
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Code that I'm using --

```
URL h1 = new URL(crazyLink)
HttpURLConnection huc1 = (HttpURLConnection) h1.openConnection();
huc1.setRequestMethod("GET");
huc1.connect();
if(huc1.getResponseCode() == 200){
    System.out.println("Passed");
}else{
    System.out.println("Failed");
}
```

I've tried changing `FirefoxProfile` to `ignore ssl`, but it didn't work --

```
firefoxProfile profile=new firefoxProfile();
Profile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
driver=new firefoxDriver(profile);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the url you are trying to hit require authentication?  Does it prompt for a user/password if you hit it directly within your browser in an incognito window?

Comment: @SamWoods I tried in incognito window by directly pasting the link. It doesn't require any authentication. The link itself has a guid and goes directly in the landing page which does not have an authentication page. If I tried without the guid, it does go to the authentication page. Please let me know if you need any more info. Thank you so much for responding.

Comment: Which FirefoxWebDriver version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is not related to HTTP Basic Authentication, i.e., is not about missing authentication credentials. This also has nothing to do with broken links. This bizzarre exception message is saying that in your truststore you do not have certificate of the Web site you want to connect to, so simply that you do not trust this site.

Now the solution depends on which of your code excerpts we're talking about. For the first you should use `HttpsURLConnection` instead of `HttpURLConnection`, because you're trying to connect to SSL-protected URL. Then you should:

- download site's certificate and add it to your local trusstore, or
- [use trust manager that does not validate certificate chains for SSL sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201048/allowing-java-to-use-an-untrusted-certificate-for-ssl-https-connection).

For the second code which uses WebDriver it may depend on [which library version are using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975927/webdriver-ssl-certificate-accepting-not-working-on-sub-domain). So which one are you using?

Answer (score 1):

True to edit user3783352's answer but got some permission error. So here is the content of the post referred to in that answer-

```
package <Your Package>;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class CheckLinks {
public static int invalidLink;
String currentLink;
String temp;
public static int responsecode;
public static boolean isValid = false;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
// Launch The Browser
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// Enter Url
driver.get(“<URLre>”);

//Check css & favicon
try
{
List<WebElement> no = driver.findElements(By.tagName(“link”));
int nooflinks = no.size();
System.out.println(“Total CSS & Favicon Icons: ” + nooflinks);
for (WebElement pagelink : no)
{
String linktext = pagelink.getText();
String link = pagelink.getAttribute(“href”);
URL u = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection h = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
h.setRequestMethod(“GET”);
h.connect();
int responsecode = h.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(linktext+”\t” + link + “\t” + “Response Code: ” + responsecode);
//System.out.println(link);
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}

//Check Javascripts
try
{
List<WebElement> no = driver.findElements(By.tagName(“script”));
int nooflinks = no.size();
System.out.println(“Total Javascripts: ” + nooflinks);
for (WebElement pagelink : no)
{
String linktext = pagelink.getText();
String link = pagelink.getAttribute(“src”);
URL u = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection h = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
h.setRequestMethod(“GET”);
h.connect();
int responsecode = h.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(linktext+”\t” + link + “\t” + “Response Code: ” + responsecode);
//System.out.println(link);
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}

//Check Images
try
{
List<WebElement> no = driver.findElements(By.tagName(“img”));
int nooflinks = no.size();
System.out.println(“Total Images: ” + nooflinks);
for (WebElement pagelink : no)
{
String linktext = pagelink.getAttribute(“alt”);
String link = pagelink.getAttribute(“src”);
URL u = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection h = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
h.setRequestMethod(“GET”);
h.connect();
int responsecode = h.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(linktext+”\t” + link + “\t” + “Response Code: ” + responsecode);
//System.out.println(link);
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}

//Check hyperlinks.
try
{
List<WebElement> no = driver.findElements(By.tagName(“a”));
int nooflinks = no.size();
System.out.println(“Total hyperlinks: ” + nooflinks);
for (WebElement pagelink : no)
{
String linktext = pagelink.getText();
String link = pagelink.getAttribute(“href”);
URL u = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection h = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
h.setRequestMethod(“GET”);
h.connect();
int responsecode = h.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(linktext+”\t” + link + “\t” + “Response Code: ” + responsecode);
//System.out.println(link);
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
System.out.println(“— End of Test —“);

driver.close();
driver.quit();
}
}
```

Now I can easily check broken links on a web page with this piece of code.